# Rolling out K8s without Flink disruptions

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink

Are there any special precautions that need to be taken for undergoing
regular K8s maintenance procedures such as migrating/upgrading clusters?

For the sake of concreteness, I'm running my jobs via the Flink K8s
Operator and I'm finding that when rolling out new nodes and migrating my
jobs to them in some cases they get stuck and/or don't restart properly, or
do so multiple times causing more downtime than expected.

As of now my migration/rollout process is as follows:

- Create new K8s nodes/instances
- Cordon old ones to be replaced (where my jobs are running)
- Take savepoints
- Drain old nodes
- Wait until all jobs show up as RUNNING and STABLE in the new nodes

Nothing special here I would say. However, I wonder if there are any best
practices for Flink specifically which help minimize the downtime/potential
failures during these maintenance windows. Things such as tweaking budget
disruption policies and/or pod affinities, or maybe considering a HA setup
with multiple jobmangers vs just one. To be clear, all my jobs are deployed like this (in application mode):

```
apiVersion: flink.apache.org/v1beta1
kind: FlinkDeployment
...
spec:
  ...
  mode: native
```

and for what it's worth, their HA setup is based on the native K8s mode (vs
Zookeeper) and a single jobmanager.

Comment: Potentially related: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-24237.

Answer (score 1):

Best practices for minimizing downtimes and potential failures during these maintenance windows can be very subjective, here are some suggestions that can lower the margin of error.

Make sure the version of the Flink K8s operator and the application is stable and tested to ensure consistency. Using the latest version can increase the stability of the system.

Regarding HA setup for Flink, try deploying multiple JobManagers as this ensures lesser downtimes and is always on as if one goes down, another JobManager can replace.

Also if possible try using monitor tools such as Grafana and Prometheus for a more comprehensive monitoring and real time updates.

Hope these suggestions can help you create a more organized system and avoid unwanted failures.